# copying a string read from a file and storing it in a two dimensional string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

This is my code to copy a string from file and storing it in a two dimensional string array.

```
  char str1[5000][2000];
  while (NULL != fgets(str, 2000, fp))
  {
    memcpy(str1[i][2000], str, 2000 * sizeof(char));
    i=++line_number;

   }
```

But my execution stops suddenly. How could I copy the string from file and store it in a string array?

Comment: Why are you creating such a huge array? Or actually: Creating huge such array why you?

Answer (score 0):

Expression

```
str1[i][2000]
```

has type `char` while function `memcpy` requires that the first argument would be of type `void *`.

You could write instead

```
char str1[5000][2000];
size_t n = 0;

while ( n < 5000 && fgets( str1[n], sizeof( *str1 ), fp ) != NULL )
{
    str1[n][strcspn( str1[n], "\n" )] = '\0';
    ++n;
}
```

In this case variable `n` will contain the number of read lines.

Also it is better when the array has the static storage duration (or dynamically allocated) because it is too large as for example

```
static char str1[5000][2000];
```

Comment: note `str1` is too large for the automatic variable